# Trying to upload image from iPhone to server with PHP

Tags: php, ios, image, upload

```
 if ($_REQUEST['device_type'] == '1') {

       $fileName = $_FILES['media_chunk']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['media_chunk']['tmp_name'];
        //$fileSize = $_FILES['imageData']['size'];
       //$fileType = $_FILES['imageData']['type'];

        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content1 = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

         $file_name = $db->host . 'snaps/' . $_REQUEST['media_name']; // . $owner_id

         $file_to_open = 'snaps/' . $_REQUEST['media_name'];

        $handle = fopen($file_to_open, 'a');
        fwrite($handle, $content);
        fclose($handle);

        $msg = new getErrorMsg('0');
        $json = array('FilePath' => $file_name, 'statusMessage' => $msg->errMsg, 'statusNumber' => $msg->errNo);
        echo json_encode($json);
        return false;
```

The data isn't being uploaded through device. Works when I fill out form from desktop but not through iPhone.

Path is created however just not the data

Comment: Presumably the request is not properly formatted by your iOS code. Watch the request from both web browser and from app with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and see how the requests differ. The problem undoubtedly rests in your iOS code, but rather than us pouring through some code, you should first do some diagnostics to identify how they differ, and the problem will probably jump right out at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making it device independent?
i.e by removing this code:

```
 if ($_REQUEST['device_type'] == '1') {
```